# Is it possible to hide a view until the animation is finished or while it is running?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-transitions

I'm trying to show and hide an animated linearlayout, using TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition, and this is the result I get:

[image]

when I make the view visible it works fine, but when the hidden one disappears immediately and then the animation happens, is it possible to delay the hiding?

I attach the sample code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        binding.btn.setOnClickListener {
            val transition = ChangeBounds()
            transition.addTarget(binding.ly1)
            transition.addTarget(binding.ly2)
            TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(
                binding.root, transition
            )
            binding.ly1.visibility = if (binding.ly1.isVisible) View.GONE else View.VISIBLE
        }
    }
}

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ly1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/ly2"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ly2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/teal_200"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/ly1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="test" />
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Animation.AnimationListener` with 3 methods that you can do anything from any point of time during the process:

```
animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener(){

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
    }           

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
    }           

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
    }
});
```

Here's the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener)